# I won’t be a jiffy

Tags: difference, antonyms

The following sentences seem to mean the same. However, "a jiffy" is a short time, but "long" refers to a long time. Why is that? What's the basis for understanding the sentences when the boldfaced words have opposite meanings?

> I’ve just got to fetch some books from upstairs - I won’t be a **jiffy**.

> I’ve just got to fetch some books from upstairs - I won’t be **long**.

Comment: @BillyKerr The phrase you say is not idiomatic at all and doesn't make sense is the example found in Cambridge Dictionary for "jiffy"

Comment: @Astralbee - then I suppose I it's because I don't know it, or don't use it.  Reminds me of the incorrect "I could care less" and the correct "I couldn't care less" debacle. I just wouldn't say "I won't be a jiffy" when I literally will be a jiffy.

Comment: As jiffy is an indeterminate short period of time, you can use it just the way you would a minute. "I won't be a minute." No-one is actually going to time you. I often use the 'yonk' in a joking manner - "I haven't seen John in at least a yonk & a half." as though it was a measurable time period.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - each to their own. LOL;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't mean exactly the same thing.

There are several words and phrases that mean *a moment* or *a very short period of time*. Some of these are predominantly British, but among them are 'jiffy', 'mo' (short for 'moment') and 'tick' (like a tick of the clock, a second). Some of these are hyperbole, of course. Saying you "won't be a jiffy" means you will be so fast it *won't even* be that length of time. These are things you might say if you think the amount of time is negligible, barely noticeable.

Saying you won't be "long" is less hyperbolic. If you won't be a *long* period of time then you must only intend to be a *short* period of time. This is something you would more likely say when you expect to be some time, but it will not be excessive.

Comment: I think the difference between the two expressions is less clear cut than you suggest.

Comment: Wha't being omitted after "be" in the OP example?

Comment: Nothing is being omitted. You could expand it to "I won't be as long as a jiffy" but no-one actually would.

Comment: "I won't be a jiffy" may mean that *it will be done in the blink of an eye* OR *it will take quite some time* (because I don't exactly know where these books are).

Comment: @DoneWithThis. It's hard for someone whose native language isn't English to see why nothing is being omitted there. After all, you could say I am a human being, I'm short, etc., but how can a person be a period of time, literally speaking?

Comment: @Graffito - as a UK speaker I would only use it to mean 'I won't be very long' (for some value of 'long'). If I suspected that I might take some time I would say something different, maybe 'I might be more than a jiffy'.

Comment: We describe a person who isn't short as _tall_, not _long. I won't be long_ is idiomatic for _I won't take a long time_ or _I won't be away for long._